# Error when trying to use the new Active Record Query Interface in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the [new Active Record Query Interface](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface) for Rails 3.

My old style query is

```
my_notes = Note.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_id => current_user.id, :date => p[:date] }, :order => "date ASC, created_at ASC")
```

In the new style, I thought it would be:

```
my_notes = Note.find_all_by_user_id_and_date(current_user.id, p[:date]).order('date ASC, created_at ASC')
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in NotesController#play
undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x00000103d23c38>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Comment: It appears that `find_all` returns an array. Perhaps you can switch to `where`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new query interface works slightly differently - `find_all_by_user_id_and_date` will return an array of results, whereas `order` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object that can then be further scoped.

A working query would be

```
my_notes = Note.order('date ASC, created_at ASC').find_all_by_user_id_and_date(current_user.id, p[:date])
```

but it would generally be better to use the AREL syntax for your query:

```
my_notes = Note.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :date => p[:date]).order('date ASC, created_at ASC').all
```

Comment: @Ariejan Not at the time I posted my answer it wasn't, you added extra info after I posted.

Comment: Hey that's what I said first! (though in a brief comment) :) You both have explained it well: +1s all around.

Answer (score 6):

`find_all_by_<attritubte>` is not part of the new ARel syntax. It executes the query immediately and returns an Array with the results. Because the query has already been executed, you can't add any more options, like `order` to it.

Try this instead:

```
Note.find.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :date => p[:date]).order('date ASC, created_at ASC')
```